# How can I create mask on a plot in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to create a mask of any color, just like in the figure. Here I have used black.

[image: Pseudocolor image with black shape superimposed]

Comment: `fill_between` or `Patch`?

Comment: You could also use `set_under` when using the colormap if those points are defined as -999 or something to that effect. Add some sample code and data for more help.

Comment: @BenT Dear Bent as you are an atmospheric scientist, you will understand, I have created a max-z product [Figure](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FG7MrrvVPyTM7Y5u6hgqwNjOvWpqK340/view?usp=sharing). The top and right panel is its vertical profile. Now if you see the top and right panel the reflectivity starts above 1.3 km because the radar is located at a height of 1.3 km. Now why i need to add a separate patch is because the earth curvature, as after every 60 km the earth curvature increases by 1 km, so here the patch should mask the values up to 2 km at edges and nothing at center.

Comment: The easiest way to add a patch for the area below the radar beam will be dependent on your data and if your plot is customizable. For instance if you can change the axis of your cross-sections then you will need to transfer the equation for the bend of the radar beam from polar coordinates. In that case you should use  `fill_between` and shade the area between the surface and beam height. `set_under` would be called on your colormap and would only work if you have a ground flag in your data.

Comment: @BenT, Hi... I have attached a data file [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BtnPfcOQ8cyYYZ6sX9w-CGOlyD8aJiQB/view?usp=sharing) and [script](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13_T1Y8eJi311ZeXulb0rdn8LSJaQcxbX/view?usp=sharing), please have a look and see if it is possible.

Comment: You can download the [notebook](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bi4m5ckvFYq4QiCEEaagQ1Gsc18SkeTh/view?usp=sharing) also, if you want to.

Comment: So do you need help with getting the lower boundary of the radar beam or plotting it? You are displaying the maximum radar reflectivity in your code along the lat/lon axis, so you will have a different beam height depending on the azimuth of your maximum.

Comment: No, In simple words I need to add an extra layer to the plot which will cover the lower 0 to 2 km of Height with a minimum at the center and maximum along edges so that it should cover the reflectivity values under the lowest elevation angle. [Example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1K9I8NK8QWDa7dz2H5u6VER_CcnHPZbbb/view?usp=sharing), the curvature should depend according to earths curvature as after every 60 km, the curvature increases by 1 km. If you plot a simple plot as an example attached, I can then plot it on the max-z product.

Comment: @Bent if you still can't imagine, here is the example of the Indian Meteorological Department (IMD) Radar plots from which you can clearly see the mask [IMD1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VhLwfPhnoyXJNzGQjh2wzPUUvWPH3ef4/view?usp=sharing) and [IMD2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CO5uv5aBZonJsO1lssVjl53BYXYbZeXj/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I think you are a bit confused because of your changing coordinate system. Yes, the beam height changes because of the earths curvature, but because you are plotting in lat/lon, your height/distance dependence needs to be converted from polar coordinates to cartesian coordinates. The simple 1km/60km is a 3rd order approximation that doesn't include beam refraction or your coordinate system transform. If you really want to plot that approximation then you need to calculate the distance from the radar in km and then divide by 60 km

Comment: You should really give this a try and I think you will figure it out. The mask you want is in reality dynamic (dependent on atmospheric conditions) and will depend on the location of the maximum reflectivity you are plotting. I would suggest  googling radar beam height equation and plotting the beam height first.